# Oracle SQL join subquery with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

EDIT: Added sample results under each code snippet as well as desired results at the end.

I have been looking through several posts but I can't seem to find a solution I can apply exactly. I have a table `r` which contains data by `acctnbr` and then by `modnbr`. For most `acctnbrs` there is only one record and the resulting `modnbr` is 1, but there can be up to 5 records with `modnbrs` of 1-5.

Table `u` does not have `modnbr` so I want to do a left join on `acctnbr` and only return the value from table `u` for the max `modnbr` per `acctnbr` in table `r`.

Here is my code without attempting that join. I need to include the other qualifier on the join as shown:

```
select
r.acctnbr,
r.modnbr,
r.modtypcd,
r.moddate,
u.userfieldcd,
u.value

from loanrestructuretracking r 

LEFT JOIN acctuserfield u on u.acctnbr = r.acctnbr 
and u.userfieldcd = 'LOMO'

order by r.moddate desc
```

As expected, I am getting the same `u.value` for each `r.acctnbr` regardless of `modnbr`. Here are the results:

```
+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| acctnbr | modnbr | modtypcd |  moddate   | userfieldcd | value |
+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| 1122330 |      1 | LM       | 1/1/2018   | LOMO        | DLQ   |
| 1223340 |      1 | LM       | 2/5/2018   | LOMO        | DLQ   |
| 2233440 |      1 | LM       | 6/9/2017   | LOMO        | COT   |
| 2233440 |      2 | LM       | 11/20/2017 | LOMO        | COT   |
| 2233440 |      3 | LM       | 3/12/2018  | LOMO        | COT   |
| 3344550 |      1 | LM       | 4/27/2018  | LOMO        | EXT   |
| 3344550 |      2 | LM       | 6/2/2018   | LOMO        | EXT   |
+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

Now, here is the code I tried attempting to look for the max `modnbr` but I now I am only seeing `u.value` for any instance of the max `modnbr` (in my case, 5.)

```
select
r.acctnbr,
r.modnbr,
r.modtypcd,
r.moddate,
u.userfieldcd,
u.value

from loanrestructuretracking r 

LEFT JOIN acctuserfield u on u.acctnbr = r.acctnbr 
and u.userfieldcd = 'LOMO'
and r.modnbr = (select max(modnbr) from loanrestructuretracking)

order by r.moddate desc
```

Here are the results of the above script. Note that there is only a `u.value` for the record with the max `modnbr`:

```
+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| acctnbr | modnbr | modtypcd |  moddate   | userfieldcd | value |
+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| 1122330 |      1 | LM       | 1/1/2018   | LOMO        |       |
| 1223340 |      1 | LM       | 2/5/2018   | LOMO        |       |
| 2233440 |      1 | LM       | 6/9/2017   | LOMO        |       |
| 2233440 |      2 | LM       | 11/20/2017 | LOMO        |       |
| 2233440 |      3 | LM       | 3/12/2018  | LOMO        | COT   |
| 3344550 |      1 | LM       | 4/27/2018  | LOMO        |       |
| 3344550 |      2 | LM       | 6/2/2018   | LOMO        |       |
+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

Lastly, here is the desired result - u.value for the max `modnbr` for each `acctnbr` and null for any record that isn't the max `modnbr` for that `acctnbr`:

```
+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| acctnbr | modnbr | modtypcd |  moddate   | userfieldcd | value |
+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
| 1122330 |      1 | LM       | 1/1/2018   | LOMO        | DLQ   |
| 1223340 |      1 | LM       | 2/5/2018   | LOMO        | DLQ   |
| 2233440 |      1 | LM       | 6/9/2017   | LOMO        |       |
| 2233440 |      2 | LM       | 11/20/2017 | LOMO        |       |
| 2233440 |      3 | LM       | 3/12/2018  | LOMO        | COT   |
| 3344550 |      1 | LM       | 4/27/2018  | LOMO        |       |
| 3344550 |      2 | LM       | 6/2/2018   | LOMO        | EXT   |
+---------+--------+----------+------------+-------------+-------+
```

What do I need to do to get the join working on the max `modnbr` per `acctnbr`? 
Thanks!

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample .. your actual result and the expected  result

Comment: Let me put together some dummy data as I can't share the actual results

Comment: @scaisEdge updated

Comment: coherent data for table  loanrestructuretracking  and table acctuserfield  are useful too .. i can't understand how you get the result without the starting data ..

Comment: if i could provide more data I would.... in a nutshell, loanrestructuretracking has acctnbr & modnbr as its PK and acctuserfield only has acctnbr as PK. Modnbr is sequential - modnbr = 3 is more recent than modnbr = 2, while value in acctuserfield is the value for the most recent modnbr. I only want the value of the most recent modnbr for each acctnbr. It is incorrect to assign the value for the most recent modnbr to all modnbrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got:

```
with base_qry as
(
  select
  r.acctnbr,
  r.modnbr,
  r.modtypcd,
  r.moddate,
  u.userfieldcd,
  u.value,
  max(r.modnbr ) over (partition by r.acctnbr) as max_modnbr

  from loanrestructuretracking r 

  LEFT JOIN acctuserfield u on u.acctnbr = r.acctnbr 
  and u.userfieldcd = 'LOMO'
)
select 
  acctnbr,
  modnbr,
  modtypcd,
  moddate,
  userfieldcd,
  case when modnbr = max_modnbr then value else null end as value
from base_query
order by moddate desc
```

don't have data so not 100% sure, but I think that will give you what you're looking for.

max(r.modnbr ) over (partition by r.acctnbr) as max_modnbr appends the maximum modnbr for each acctnbr to every row.

Then the case statement replaces the value with null on the rows where that doesn't match.

Could write the whole thing more compactly as:

```
select
  r.acctnbr,
  r.modnbr,
  r.modtypcd,
  r.moddate,
  u.userfieldcd,
  case when modnbr = max(r.modnbr ) over (partition by r.acctnbr) 
       then u.value else null end as value

  from loanrestructuretracking r 

  LEFT JOIN acctuserfield u on u.acctnbr = r.acctnbr 
  and u.userfieldcd = 'LOMO'
```

Comment: Beautiful - it works. Thanks for updating with the smaller version, my permission level requires me to start every query with SELECT so CTE's are out of the question.

Comment: Glad to help - the analytics functions are pretty useful.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
select . . .
from (select r.*, row_number() over (partition by r.acctnbr order by r.modnbr desc) as seqnum
      from loanrestructuretracking r
     ) r left join 
     acctuserfield u
     on u.acctnbr = r.acctnbr and
        u.userfieldcd = 'LOMO'
where seqnum = 1
order by r.moddate desc;
```

Comment: This is effective in returning only records for the max modnbr but I am looking for nulls when the modnbr is not the max for each acctnbr.